# Acessing TCP protocol data on net.Socket()

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to do an analysis of MariaDB/MySQL packets through Node. I've gotten pretty much everything, however, when a packet is larger than ~64K it's split into smaller packets. This means that the socket `"data"` event will be called several times, however, it is not possible to know when the data finished being produced by the server (unless I parse the incoming payload and it's producing a valid packet, which is quite counterproductive).

Reading more about it, I realized that the TCP protocol itself has flags that can help through the `ACK` and `PSH` flags (which, as far as I understood, would be the last packet sent).

So, if I receive 1MB from server, it means that my package will be splitted into 16 packets of 64KB each, and the first 15 will only have the `ACK` flag and the last `ACK` & `PSH`.

**How can I get this information in `net.Socket()`?**

It seems to me that Node does not allow directly accessing information from the TCP protocol itself, and properties like `bytesReaded`, `readableLength` or `readableHighWatermark` don't have information that helps me.

This is my current code:

```
  private send(write: Buffer, onData: OnDataCallback) {
    const buffers: Buffer[] = [];
    const rebuild: OnDataCallback = (partial) => {
      // Here we read() from Socket the SQL command response from Server:
      buffers.push(partial);

      // Event must be off() when all data reach: if(...) { ... }
      this.socket.off("data", rebuild);
      // Then complete data is concat() and submitted to callback:
      onData(Buffer.concat(buffers));
    };

    this.socket.on("data", rebuild);

    // Here we write() to Socket a SQL command:
    this.socket.write(write);
  }
```

Comment: TCP is simply an ordered stream protocol.  Incoming packets can be delivered at any time and the ONLY way to know which packets go with which other packets is to parse/understand the data to know when one `data` event stands on its own vs. is part of several transmissions.  Plus, the size of `data` packets can also depend upon the network it transits over.  So, if you were suddenly running all this over a 300 baud modem or over a slow satellite connection, you might see very different grouping of packets into a `data` event based on transit time, lost packets, retransmission, etc...

Comment: `data` events are simply the next streamed chunk of TCP data to arrive and can only be reliably understood at the application level by parsing as a given data event may contain multiple application level operations or only a part of an application level operation.

Comment: If you're doing this as the base TCP level, then application level parsing of the incoming data will be required to reliably do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get this information in `net.Socket` on NodeJS (or any other user-level application). The flags on the TCP packets are handled by the kernel which re-assembled the data stream for the consuming application (your node app). The details of the tcp packets, flags, sequence numbers, ... are all handled by the kernel only and can not be accessed by a user-level application.

All you see from there is that some new data is available, but you will have no reliable information about when it arrived, in which order it arrived or if there were e.g. missing packages which were retransmitted.

To access the packet-level data, you need to use something lower in the stack, commonly a tool called [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org/), to get the raw packet details from the kernel.

Also, the `PSH` flag is an optimization used by MariaDB/MySQL to ensure that data sent in the last package of a response is delivered quicker by the receiving kernel to the client application, instead of potentially waiting for more packets to arrive. You should likely not reply on this flag's presence to detect when a reply was completely send. For that, you actually have to parse the mysql protocol.